# Import library file in located in own directory (not root directory)

Tags: python

I have the following map structure:

```
.
├── start.py
├── lib
│   ├── lib1.py
│   ├── lib2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── scripts
│   ├── script.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

In start.py I import a script

```
from scripts import script
```

In script.py I import a library

```
from lib import lib1, lib2
```

In lib1.py, I import lib2

```
import lib2
```

Unfortunately, the last import does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "start.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scripts import script
File "xxx/scripts/script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib import lib1, lib2
File "xxx/lib/lib1.py", line 17, in <module>
    import lib2 as lib2xxx
ImportError: No module named 'lib2'
```

Changing

```
import lib2
```

to

```
from lib import lib2
```

works, but the library files are automatically generated so I prefer not to change this.

Any ideas/help?
Thanks.

Comment: But `lib2.py` is a part of the `lib` module tree? There for you should do `from lib import lib2`. They share the same folder, yes, but according to your `PATH` which will always be either the `/var/lib/python/site-packages/` or current working directory.. This script belongs to the `lib` module and should there for be imported as such. It's by design unless I'm off my wagon here.

Comment: set extra pythonpath to <project-directory>/lib/ in bashrc file and source your bashrc file after that

Comment: Changing PATH is not a solution to this, it's a workaround. The proper way to do that is what Torxed says.